# navigating between textfields of uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, navigation, uitextfield

I am making an coredata application in which I was instructed to make a tableview (filling form) with textfield in each row which I did successfully. Then I made a toolbar with previous and next button and add to textField's inputAccsoryView for navigating between the textfields of each cell. One textfield per row . I am also able to do the magic with previous and next button methods . Now the problem :

> Suppose I have 3 sections . In first section 4 rows . In second section 6 rows and in the last section 1 row . Now when I start from the 1st row and presses next till the 11th row it is working properly but then I press next nothing happens as the first row is dequeued I get "nil" for it . The code I am using :

configuring the cell

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"tag inside:%i",tag);

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                   reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];


    UITextField *theTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 170, 25)];

    theTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;  

    theTextField.delegate = self;

    theTextField.tag = tag;
    theTextField.inputAccessoryView = [self configureTheToolBar];
    [theTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];


    [cell.contentView addSubview:theTextField];
    [theTextField release];

}

cell.textLabel.text = rowLabel;
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:tag];
textField.text = rowValue
```

I am providing tags for textfield like 601 ,602 etc .

Then getting the currentTextField tag

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    currentTextField = textField.tag;
}
```

then the next method

```
if(currentTextField == 611){
        currentTextField = 601;     
    } else{
        currentTextField = currentTextField + 1;
    }
    NSLog(@"current text fiedld = %i",currentTextField);

    NSLog(@"text ; %@",[self cellForTag:currentTextField].textLabel.text);

        UITextField *firstResponderField = (UITextField *) [[self cellForTag:currentTextField].contentView viewWithTag:currentTextField];

        [firstResponderField becomeFirstResponder];
```

and the cellForTag method :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)cellForTag:(NSInteger)tag{




     UITableViewCell *cell;
            switch (tag) {
                case 601:{


                    NSUInteger onlyRow[] = {0, 0}; 
                    NSIndexPath *onlyRowPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:onlyRow length:2]; 
                    //[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:onlyRowPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

                    cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:onlyRowPath];

                    break;
}
    return cell
```

this code is working partially as once off screen cells get out of memory I can't reach textfield in that cell and next button stops working till the currentTextfield value reaches to any visiblerow . What could be the solution . *my stack is over flowed. :)*

---

Ok [this](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9882976) thread does the trick but I don't know how . can anyone explain me how ?

Answer (score 0):

Once a cell goes off screen it will no longer be accessible. Because of this you might want to grab the values of your text fields as soon as the user has finished editing them by wiring up the UIControlEventEditingDidEnd event:

```
[myTextField 
   addTarget:self 
   action:@selector(myTextChanged:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

In your myTextChanged function you can store the values away, perhaps in a dictionary if you want to keep them keyed against your tags.